# count adjacent NAs in data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I like to add an extra column "na_count" that counts adjacent NAs in the column value, like

```
value na_count
    8        0
    2        0 
   NA        4
   NA        4
   NA        4
   NA        4
    5        0
    9        0
    1        0
   NA        2
   NA        2 
    5        0
   NA        3
   NA        3
   NA        3
    8        0
    5        0
   NA        1
```

Is there perhaps a way with `dplyr` window functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr` (as the author asked for).  We create a grouping column by taking the difference of logical vector (`!is.na(value)`), compare with 1 and do the `cumsum`, then create the 'NA_count' by multiplying the logical vector with number of elements in the group (`n()`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  select(-na_count) %>% #removing the column that was not needed
  group_by(grp=cumsum(c(TRUE,abs(diff(!is.na(value)))==1))) %>% 
  mutate(NA_count = is.na(value)*n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

---

Or we can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the `rleid` of logical vector (`is.na(value)`), we get the nrow (`.N`), multiply with the logical vector and extract the 'V1' column.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, .N*is.na(value) ,rleid(is.na(value))]$V1
#[1] 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 2 2 0 3 3 3 0 0 1
```

If this is to create a new column,

```
setDT(df1)[, Na_count:= .N*is.na(value) ,rleid(is.na(value))]
```

---

Or we can use `rle` (run length encoding) from `base R`.  We get the `rle` of 'value' that are NA (`is.na(df1$value)`) in a `list`, use `within.list` to change the 'values' i.e. `TRUE` elements by using that as index to the corresponding 'lengths' and then return the atomic vector with `inverse.rle`.

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(is.na(df1$value)),
                {values[values] <- lengths[values] }))
#[1] 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 2 2 0 3 3 3 0 0 1
```

Or a slightly more compact version is

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(is.na(df1$value)), values <-lengths*values))
#[1] 0 0 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 2 2 0 3 3 3 0 0 1
```

Comment: cool, thank you... stupid that you can not accept two solutions ... but that's the exact answer to my question, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not with dplyr, but using `rle` from base-R:

```
# get run-length of missings
dd_rle <- rle(is.na(dd$value))

# use rep: value is length if missing, 0 otherwise, number of repetitions
# is length of runs
# na_count2 so comparison to expected output possible
dd$na_count2 <- rep(ifelse(dd_rle$values, dd_rle$lengths, 0),
                    dd_rle$lengths)
```